# Is there any way to know if xdebug is debuggin the current execution?

Tags: php, xdebug

How can I know in PHP if there is a debugging session? I guess it's when... there is a listening connection. Or when there is a condition to be working (f.e. the cookie XDEBUG_SESSION_START exists)

Comment: Set a breakpoint and if it stops there XDEBUG is running

Comment: it's the cookie XDEBUG_SESSION, not XDEBUG_SESSION_START

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function called xdebug_is_debugger_active() that you can use to check if there is a debugger currently attached.

Reference of all xdebug_ functions here: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions

You can also check first if the function exists, in case your code runs where no xdebug us loaded.

```
if (function_exists("xdebug_is_debugger_active") && xdebug_is_debugger_active()) {
    var_dump("I'm being debugged!");
}
```